# In a class method, what is the difference between using variable from Classname. vs cls

Tags: python

In a class method, what is the difference between using variable from Classname.Varname vs cls.Varname ?

Comment: If you use `cls.var`, this will use the class that calls the method. This means that if you subclass `classname`, `cls` may not equal `classname`. On the other hand, if you use `classname`, you are being specific about which class you are referencing.

Comment: what do you mean by subclass classname - can you explain please

Comment: Please see my answer below. It should explain what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

The effect depends on whether you are subclassing:

```
class Parent:
    @classmethod
    def use_cls(cls):
        return cls.__name__

    @classmethod
    def use_classname(cls):
        return Parent.__name__


class Child(Parent):
    pass
```

Now in the shell:

```
>>> p, c= Parent(), Child()
>>> p.use_cls()
'Parent'
>>> p.use_classname()
'Parent'
```

With the subclass we get differing results:

```
>>> c.use_cls()
'Child'
>>> c.use_classname()
'Parent'
```